# CoreData change relationships in a loop

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, relationship

I have a simple model like this:

```
item  category --> category 
      <--- items
```

and following data:

```
item A -> category blue
item B -> category blue
item C -> category blue
item D -> category green
item E -> category green
```

What I want to achieve is to change all items where the category is green to blue.

Following code produced only an error:

Two categories already exist:

```
blueCategory
greenCategory


for (Item *aItem in [greenCategory.items]) {
    [aItem setCategory:blueCategory];
}
```

Error:

> 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <_NSFaultingMutableSet: 0x8a0ef70> was mutated while being enumerated.'

My Question is: How could I alter the category in items within a loop?

Comment: I think the problem here is that a NSSet is unordered, try putting your collection in an NSArray and loop over it.

Comment: @ggfela You have the right idea, but for the wrong reason. See my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you can't change (mutate) a collection like your `greenCategory.items` set while you're looping over it, which is what you're doing when you change the category of the items in that set. What you have to do is create a separate collection and loop over it instead.

```
NSArray *greenCategoryItemsArray = [greenCategory.items allObjects];

for (Item *aItem in greenCategoryItemsArray) {
    [aItem setCategory:blueCategory];
}
```

Comment: That was fast! I tested ist already and it worked like a charm! Thanks!